# ImageMagick - "CORE_RL_magick_.dll not found" or how to install RMagick on windows with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm working on a Rail3 app.
After struggling for several hours and finally installing the rmagick 2.13.1 gem without errors on win7x64 / ruby 1.9.2, I've run into another error. Yeah, I've heard that rails experience in windows could be painfull...

I use carrierwave to process and upload images to  AWS S3.
Processing looks like

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

require 'rmagick'
include CarrierWave::RMagick
... 
process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]
process :convert => :png
...
```

When I trigger file upload on my development machine, it throws me a windows popup, saying

> CORE_RL_magick_.dll not found

Google wasn't really helpful on this one.

I have my PATH variable set to C:/ruby192/ImageMagick - its where I have installed ImageMagick to. And this folder has several CORE_RL dlls including the *magick* one. **The DLL's themselves are not missing!**

`irb > require 'rmagick'` returns true
and `convert -version` outputs this:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-6 2011-04-14 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

So I have several question.

1. How do I solve this?
2. `elseif` I don't, are there any other gems and/or graphic libraries that are supported by both windows and heroku?
3. `else` maybe there is a way to configure carrierwave, not to process images in dev environment

So far I've tried ImageMagick v 6.6.9 32bit dll, which gives the CORE_RL dll error,
64 bit static, which doesn't have dev headers to compile the rmagick gem, 
and 64 bit dynamic, which gives me tonns of `undefined reference` errors during the gem compilation, every test, except the first one:

```
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
and so on...
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've finally managed to install ImageMagick and build the RMagick gem and make it all work. Hooray.

It seems like the problem was in the DLL itself. When I tried to registed it, windows gave me a nice error about a problem with the dll.

So my way of solving all the issues is:

1. Go [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
2. Download ImageMagick 6.6.1-10 **32bit** dynamic or any other version **except the currently latest release 6.6.9, which has some DLL issues**
3. Install it with options: Add to PATH and development headers. **Installation path should not contain spaces**.
   After the installation it should give you a message box about succesful dll registration.
4. In the command line type convert -version to check if everything works. It should print something like:

   Version: ImageMagick 6.6.1-10 2010-05-15 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   Features: OpenMP
5. Install the [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) if you haven't already.
6. Install the rmagick gem: `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ruby192/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ruby192/ImageMagick/include`

It should print

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

And after a few minutes if everything goes right, you should see

```
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
```

And that's it. Hope this saves somebody from wasting several hours in frustration.

Just two more links that were helpful: [1](https://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html) and [2](https://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/12/if-you-fail-install-rmagick-on-mingw.html) if you still can't install

Comment: Cheers mate, glad you got it sorted. Pretty impressed heroku has IM as well. I wasn't aware of that so thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks a lot, I tried many tutorials, only this step by step worked for me. <3

Comment: Glad this helped, Lucas :) Actually, I did save mine too recently, when I had to reinstall windows and all the ruby/rails stuff.

Comment: Funy fact: it only worked on one computer and not the other (both with same version of ruby/rails/windows...). And the other links didn't help. *sad face*

Comment: I had to update RubyGem with `gem update --system`. At least, everything works but I get this warning message when running Rails server. `NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01`.

Answer (score 2):

This was a pain to get installed. Right now at this moment, I had to reinstall Ruby, Rails, the Devkit and ImageMagick. You're best bet is to do the same and go with the latest versions of all of them except Rails, unless your cool with 3.1. At this moment I am using the latest versions:

```
ImageMagick-6.7.2-1-Q16-windows-dll - Win32 dynamic at 16 bits-per-pixel

DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20110712-1620-sfx

rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p290

Rails 3.0.9
```

My system:

Windows 7, x64

My path is a little different from the accepted answer.

My c:/ImageMagick

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include
```

I installed Ruby first with all the options checked off, then  ImageMagick with the "associated path option" and "headers" checked off.

Then set up the devkit easily:

```
1) cd c:\DevKit
2) ruby dk.rb init
3) ruby dk.rb install
```

Then afterwards inside of the devkit (c:/devkit) did this and it installed without error:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include
```

If you still have issues then maybe this could help you, I was trying this but I am to unfamiliar with setting the environments and getting Step 5 to work: http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/

The Step 5 I believe can be changed into what i did inside of the Devkit instead, give it a try and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're going to run into problems trying to run it on Heroku as well because RMagick just acts as a gem to interface with the ImageMagick processing libraries. ImageMagick needs to also be installed on the local machine as well, which I don't know you'll be able to do on Heroku. The ImageMagick installation contains the missing .dll you're after. I use it fairly frequently on a local project. Here's the link:

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=d1l695sitj9h0vdqs78vgebqc5#windows)

I'd recommend installing the 64-bit "static" binary from the link above. I've ran into a problem or two trying to use the dll version.

Anyways download it, install it and then add your C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8 (Or wherever yours is installed to) path to your PATH environment variable.

You should then be able to use your RMagick gem properly.

All the best.

Comment: Hey, 2potatocakes) I probably should have pointed that more clearly - I already have imagemagick installation. I've downloaded the 32bit dll version. After your post I tried the 64bit static and dynamic ones. The first one doesn't have dev headers, so I can't compile the rmagick gem. The second one gives me undefined reference errors when compiling the gem. And as far as I know, Heroku has IM installed on their servers.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps on this post, but still got a lof of undefined errors. If this is your case as well you might want to try installing the 32 version of imagemagick, despite of having a 64 bit operating system. It worked for me.
You can read more about it here: [rmagick not building on windows 7 undefined reference errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151030/rmagick-not-building-on-windows-7-undefined-reference-errors/20250733#20250733)