# Devise: Recaptcha is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

my Devise Recaptcha isn't working correctly because **I can skip right over it and still register**.

I followed the Devise wiki at - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise and got everything working accept i encountered the problem above.

Here is my code:

**app/controllers/users/registrations.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        if verify_recaptcha
            super
        else
            build_resource
            clean_up_passwords(resource)
            flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
            render_with_scope :new
        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users do
    root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "/" => "devise/registrations#new"
    post '/' => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
    match '/', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'    
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  namespace :user do
    root :to => "home#index"
  end
```

**config/initializers/recaptcha.rb**

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
    config.public_key  = 'mykey123456789'
    config.private_key = 'mykey13456789'
end
```

It is possible it doesn't work because i am in test mode and not on my domain name?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with not having ImageMagick or RMagick installed, had to go through the nonsense to get this working.

These were my trials & tribulations:

[ImageMagick - "CORE_RL_magick_.dll not found" or how to install RMagick on windows with ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-window/7293655#7293655)

Answer (score 1):

In environment.rb put the following:

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']  = 'mykey123456789'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = 'mykey123456789'
```

Not being on your domain name may be a problem depending on how you registered the keys.

Comment: Is this registering the keys? i went to http://www.google.com/recaptcha and signed up, put in my website and put the keys inside the recaptcha.rb. I put your code above inside of my environment.rb and no change.

Comment: Yes, that is how you register the keys.  If you used your website, then I believe you should be using those specific keys only on your domain?  Are you on localhost or your domain?  Sorry, the environment.rb didn't help.  I looked over my use of recaptcha and did not see any other differences.

Comment: You should create a new set of keys where you use your localhost as your domain, and then switch to the ones you are currently using when you upload to production.

Comment: I tried to add the localhost by inserting -> http://localhost:3000/ but it says it must be a domain like .com or .net. By default it claims it detects localhost. I also tried new keys but still no luck.