# how do you get rmagick to work on windows 7 64-bit with rails 3.1 and carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rmagick

I'm having trouble getting rmagick to work on windows. Does anyone know how to get this working correctly? And even better, hopefully in a way that is compatible with a production environment, although I'll take whatever I can get.

```
C:\> gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=%IMAGE_MAGICK_HOME%/lib --with-opt-include=%IMAGE_MAGICK_HOME%/include
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/include
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/ruby192/bin/ruby
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Comment: @Zabba: With the devkit, it won't install properly. It needs libraries that it can't find. I've tried to download imagemagick and rmagick and compile them, but it fails when I try to compile rmagick. The devkit just isn't doing what it's supposed to do I don't think. Basically, `gem install rmagick` doesn't 'just work' - far from it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer in this thread made it work on both of my computer: [RMagick on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-window)

I hope it'll work for you too !

Comment: I did most of that. I will paste the error. Man, I wish this was easier. Rmagick is something most people will want. I wish the devkit provided some help by default. This is too hard for each and every person to go through :(

Comment: finally got it to work. i dunno what i did actually. it just started working.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I just installed rmagick into Ruby 2.1-x64 on Windows using instructions from a reddit post, reposted below:

---

Download the Ruby Development Kit from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and unpack it somewhere. (By the way, your Ruby must also have come from Rubyinstaller otherwise the dev kit says it won't work.)

Init your DevKit by doing

```
dk.rb init
```

this will create a config.yml with a list of Rubies found on your system, you may edit it and delete the ones you don't care about

```
dk.rb review
```

to make sure the previous step went well

```
dk.rb install
```

to install DevKit into that Ruby, after this is done you'll be able to compile native Ruby extensions.

Download ImageMagick from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) (ImageMagick-6.9.2-3-Q16-x64-dll.exe worked for me), and install it **to a path without spaces**. Make sure to check **Add application directory to system path** and **Install headers and libraries for C and C++**.

Restart your command line window to make sure the change to PATH took.

Do a quick set PATH to make sure ImageMagick is first in PATH, otherwise the install will fail (because an install script calls convert.exe which is from ImageMagick, but there also exists a C:\Windows\system32\convert.exe).

Run the following line, suitably replacing with the location of ImageMagick on your system (which, you remember, should not contain spaces):

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=D:/Tools/ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=D:/Tools/ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16/include --with-opt-dir=D:/Tools/ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16
```

It should churn for a couple of minutes and then you're golden.

By the way, as long as you intend to be using RMagick, you're stuck with having ImageMagick in your PATH.