# Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp

PHP 5.3.8

WAMP 2.2.21

ImageMagick 6.6.2 Q16

---

**Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found** happens no matter what.
No matter how many times I...

1. Install/reinstall different versions of ImageMagick
2. Try various VC9 builds of php_imagick.dll to 'wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext\'
3. Have updated my php.ini to include 'extension=php_imagick.dll'
4. Have restarted my pc and WAMP... I can't count how many times O_o

I also get this error on WAMP startup

[image]

---

The funny thing is that php_imagick.dll shows up in my PHP extensions via the WAMP taskbar

[image]

but not in my localhost PHP-Loaded Extensions:

[image: localhost Loaded Extensions]

---

Does anyone have any ideas to why this is happening? Or any suggestions?

---

SOLUTION: I had to learn the hard way... WAMP 2.2 x32 NOT x64, ImageMagick 6.6.4 Q16 at the greatest.

Comment: How many php.ini files can you find on this machine?

Comment: @Cups          Hmmm.. didnt't realize that I have 2. I'm gonna update the second php.ini and report back...

Comment: Watch out, one may be the CLI PHP ini file, so editing that may have unexpected consequences.  Have PHP output to you the path of the PHP ini file it is using: inspect the output of phpinfo() onto a webpage (in localhost or whatever).

Comment: The usual issue with such errors is that either one of imagick's dependencies is missing (does it have any? no idea) or that imagick and/or one of the dependencies are not binary compatible with your PHP (e.g. 32 vs 64 bit compiles).

Comment: @Cups I updated my second php.ini to incude 'extension=php_imagick.dll' and I now have a new error on WAMP startup... Something about: ...php_imagick.dll - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I have uploaded an image.

Comment: @Jon would you have any idea how I could check if my problem is resulting from a x86 vs x64 compile issue? I'm running x86 PHP + WAMP, php_imagick.dll needs a x86 build of ImageMagick to function, whick I'm running. The only thing x64 is my OS.

Comment: @Terry: [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can tell you this (and it can do much more to help debug DLL hell!). Load up the DLL and scroll to the bottom of the module list; the DLL you loaded will be in the last line. Look at the "CPU" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the `php_imagick.dll` extension.

Check first of all that the file *is* there and is readable. If it is, then it is not loading because *the DLL itself* requires some other DLL; this error isn't usually shown by Windows. You will need some tool such as [DEPENDS](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to load `php_imagick.dll` and see what unresolved externals it contains.

You will probably find that some functions are imported by a library (such as `libeay32.dll`) that is maybe associated with an extension you did not load, or is in the PHP directory but ought to have been copied into Windows' SYSTEM directory, or maybe uses a different VC runtime (e.g `MSVCR90.DLL`).

For example, a sample PHP 5.3 `php_imagick.dll` I found turns out to depend on these two DLL's

```
CORE_RL_WAND_.DLL
CORE_RL_MAGICK_.DLL
```

and guess what, CORE_RL_MAGICK *is itself depending on other symbols*, which explains the problems this guy was experiencing (his solution was maybe a bit more thorough than necessary, but hey, whatever works -- and it *might* work for you too, but read on)

[ImageMagick - "CORE_RL_magick_.dll not found" or how to install RMagick on windows with ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windo)

Looking into CORE_RL_MAGICK again with DEPENDS turns out a dependence on a specific version of Visual C++ Runtime (and QT too, for some versions of IM), which ties this in the ugly can of worms known as "VC6 against VC9" (e.g. http://www.websiteadministrator.com.au/articles/install_guides/installing_php533_pg2.html ).

Now, what should **you** do? It *depends*. Literally; for instead of blindly reinstalling at random until the stars are right (again: it *might* work. It often does!), I would fire up DEPENDS on the `imagick` DLL, then on ImageMagick core DLL, and so on, until I hunted down the maze of twisty little dependencies, all alike, that Windows ought to tell you about, but doesn't.

(That's why it's called "*DLL Hell*").

Comment: php_imagick.dll is there and readable, I even double checked ;) I'm pretty sure it doesn't need any other .dll(s) to run. I might be wrong but I have read all and behold tutorials and read forum entry after forum entry and there has never been any mention of any other .dll or placing php_imagick.dll anywhere else but my PHP extensions folder...

Comment: That might be the most useful answer that i have gotten. Ever.

Comment: @Iserni        Thanks for the help! ps. It's my first time doing this kind of thing, "DLL Hell" is an understatement.

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to also read the 'DLL Hell' entry on Wikipedia, or the Joel on Software discussion ( http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=2899 ).