# PHP 5.5.12 php_imagick.dll is not working. %1 is not a valid W32 applicaiton

Tags: php, dll, imagick, php-extension

I want to install Php ImageMagick on my system. Working from two days but couldn't install it. I have the following configuration of my system :

> PHP 5.5.12,  Wamp 2.5,  Win64 but Php uses Win32 extensions.

Here are the errors i am facing :

1. Error when i add php_imagick.dll of Win64.

[image]

2. Error when i add php_imagick.dll of Win32.

[image]

Here are the link i took help but didn't work for me.

https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues/222

[ImageMagick - "CORE_RL_magick_.dll not found" or how to install RMagick on windows with ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windo)

Please don't mark it duplicate, as i tried all the links but not working for me. Expert suggestions needed here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the imagick library here:
http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

Choose thread-safety one that corresponds to your php version and replace your imagick dll with it.

Also, don't forget to install Imagick itself: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

You need ImageMagick-*-Q16-x64-dll.exe installer file.
This worked fine for me on Windows 7 with PHP 5.5, XAMPP.

Comment: What about php 8.1?

Comment: @Bojmaliev https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick